# jQuery user-defined function not executing in if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click

I am new to learning jQuery so I've been stumped with this for a while (and excuse me if my question is very obvious).
When the user loads the site, I want the screen to append square images continuously every 5 seconds, until they click "Click Me!" which stops it. The function runForever which appends the images works on it's own if I add '$' in front of '(function)', but inside my button click function, runForever doesn't run at all. I know it doesn't run because I added an alert statement for when the user loads the page, but the page never gives me this statement. It does, however, give me the alert for when I click 'Click Me!'.

```js
   
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        (function runForever() {
            (".img-box").append("<div class='img-from-other-class'</div>");
            setTimeout(runForever, 5000);
        });
        var clicked = false;
        $("button").click(function() {
            if (clicked == false) {
                alert ("beginning repetition");
                runForever();
            }
            else {
                alert ("button clicked");
                clicked = true; 
                return;
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
     <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-6">
        <h3>jQuery Practice</h3>
       </div>
       <div class="col-6">
        <button class="float-right">
         Click Me
        </button>
       </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-12">
        <div class="img-box">
              <div class="img-from-other-class"></div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: No it won't, as it is closed, using _closure_, and have not exposed its inner function. Simply remove its outer parenthesis `(function runForever() {...})` to `function runForever() {...}`

Comment: @LGSon I see. I removed the parenthesis, but the function still is not running. I thought the problem was with the '$', but I placed it in front of my (".img-box").append("<div class='img-from-other-class'</div>"); statement but it is still not working

Comment: No, not saying that, please read my updated comment again, slowly, and see if you got what I meant.

Comment: remove the parenthesis, call `runForever()` after declaration, add `$` before `(".img-box")`

Comment: @MannuallyOverridden The problem with calling runForever() after declaration is that when the user clicks "Click Me!", it won't stop runnning the function

Answer (score 0):

style css in follow

```css
    .img-from-other-class{
       width:50px;
       height:50px;
       background:red;
       border-radius:50%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
    <button class="stop-btn">STOP</button>
    <div class="image-box"></div>
        <script>
       $(function(){
           function run(){
               interval = setInterval(function(){
               $('.image-box').append('<div class="img-from-other-class"></div>');
               }, 5000);
           }
    
    run();

// click for stop append

      $('.stop-btn').click(function(){
         clearInterval(interval);
      });
    });
    </script>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: THANK YOU ks1313!! This worked! :) Can I ask you, why don't we use '$' on the second function run() { statement? Do we need always need to define this function? Thanks again!

Comment: Your welcome , always for design function in all languages programming first define function and after call it.